# JavaScript Reduce with Objects

Tags: javascript, reduce

This is my object

```
   let products = [
      { "productName": "A", "storage": "Lot 1", "quantity": 1000, "status": "stockIn" },
      { "productName": "A", "storage": "Lot 1", "quantity": 100, "status": "stockIn"  },
      { "productName": "A", "storage": "Lot 1", "quantity": 500, "status": "stockOut" },
      { "productName": "A", "storage": "Lot 2", "quantity": 500, "status": "stockIn"  }
   ]
```

This is what I am trying to achieve

```
   let result = [
      { "productName": "A", "storage": "Lot 1", "stockIn": 1100, "stockOut": 500, "available":600 },
      { "productName": "A", "storage": "Lot 2", "stockIn": 500, "stockOut": 0, "available":500   }
   ]
```

Please kindly provide an idea on how to achieve this without redundant codes. Thanks

```
var storage = new Set(products.map(item => item.storage));

storage.forEach(lot => {

var stockIn = products.filter(item => item.storage === storage && item.status == 'stockIn')
    .map(({ storage, quantity }) => ({ storage, quantity }));

var stockInSum = stockIn.reduce((prev, curr, index) => prev + curr.quantity, 0);

var stockOut = products.filter(item => item.storage === storage && item.status == 'stockOut')
    .map(({ storage, quantity }) => ({ storage, quantity }))

var stockOutSum = stockOut.reduce((prev, curr, index) => prev + curr.quantity, 0);

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: @Andreas I have updated my code. I tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), iterate over the array while updating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where the `key` is the combination of `productName` and `storage`, and the value is the corresponding grouped object
- In every iteration, using the current key, get the pair if exist and deconstruct `stockIn` and `stockOut`. According to the current `status`, update one of the latter values and compute `available`. Finally, using [`Map#set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set), create/update the pair.
- Using [`Map#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values), get the list of grouped objects

```js
const products = [
  { productName: "A", storage: "Lot 1", quantity: 1000, status: "stockIn" },
  { productName: "A", storage: "Lot 1", quantity: 100,  status: "stockIn"  },
  { productName: "A", storage: "Lot 1", quantity: 500,  status: "stockOut" },
  { productName: "A", storage: "Lot 2", quantity: 500,  status: "stockIn"  }
];

const result = [...
  products.reduce((map, { productName, storage, quantity, status }) => {
    const key = `${productName}-${storage}`;
    let { stockIn = 0, stockOut = 0 } = map.get(key) ?? {};
    if(status === 'stockIn') stockIn += quantity;
    else stockOut += quantity;
    const available = stockIn - stockOut;
    map.set(key, { productName, storage, stockIn, stockOut, available });
    return map;
  }, new Map)
  .values()
];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Brilliant. Works like a charm. You are the man. .Thanks  bro.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general pattern.  I will leave it to you to figure out the other fields.

```js
const reduced = products.reduce( (a,v) => {
  const found = a.find(it=>it.lot === v.lot && it.productName === v.productName)
  if (found) {
    a.quantity += v.quantity
    // aggregate your other fields here.
  }
  else {
    a.push(v)
  }
  return a
}, [] )
```